# URL Routing - yii-basic-app - Yii2

Tags: php, routes, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i was trying to pass ID in URL. I was getting difficulty to do it. So, i was going through tutorials like [Larry Ullman - URL Routing](http://www.larryullman.com/2013/02/18/understanding-routes-in-the-yii-framework/).

My problem is: I created confirm.php page and created a controller too but error like NOT FOUND (#404) coming.

**SiteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\swiftmailer\Mailer;

use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\models\EntryForm;
use app\models\RegisterForm;
use app\models\LoginExecForm;
use app\models\ForgotPasswordForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
  .
  .
  public function actionConfirm($id)
    {
        $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
        return $this->render('confirm');
    }
}
```

**config/web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller>/<action:\w+>.<_format>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'v1/<controller>/<action:\w+>.<_format>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

**confirm.php**

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\captcha\Captcha;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\Url;

$this->title = 'Register';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-about">
    asd
</div>
```

> Error Coming => Not Found(#404)

[image]

After i got this error, I added few codes in **config/web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
      'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '/',
        ),
    ],
```

But, now problem is every page is redirecting to index.php page.

What to do ? I'm having No Idea. Please Help me to rectify this problem.

Comment: can you post location of `confirm.php`

Comment: yii2-app-basic/views/site/confirm.php Mr @gamitg

Comment: you have add the `.htaccess` file in `web` folder ?

Comment: i also think it is either the missing .htaccesss file or the apache (or other webserver) hasn't enabled mod_rewrite

Comment: Yeah. No .htaccess files are present in my folder

Comment: Please delete your last question and show us your actual urlManager config...

Comment: I edited my question Mr @soju

Comment: It should be `'<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'`...

Comment: After adding this code '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
   '<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>', it worked Mr @soju

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `.htaccess` file in `web` folder, for removing `index.php` from URL.

Like as,

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller>/<action:\w+>.<_format>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'v1/<controller>/<action:\w+>.<_format>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: please add in main.php under components sections

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in main.php

```
  'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<controller>/<action:\w+>.<_format>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        'v1/<controller>/<action:\w+>.<_format>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

and also add this code in .htaccessfile