# Passing Parameter To Controller - yii2-app-basic Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

> http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/site/confirm/39/

I'm manually passing 39 in upper URL to know how to work with parameters.

I want to display 39 in `confirm.php` but it's not working. As soon, i'm passing `$id` in `actionConfirm($id)` of `SiteController` Controller.
Page Not Found Error Coming. What can be the problem.

I just asked one question [URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947396/url-routing-yii-basic-app-yii2), where i got my answer. But, now here i got stuck.

**confirm.php**

```
<?php

    /* @var $this yii\web\View */

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
    use yii\captcha\Captcha;
    use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
    use yii\helpers\Url;

    $this->title = 'Contact';
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-about">
    <?echo $id;?>
</div>
```

**SiteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\swiftmailer\Mailer;

use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\models\EntryForm;
use app\models\RegisterForm;
use app\models\LoginExecForm;
use app\models\ForgotPasswordForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function actionConfirm($id)
    {

        $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
        return $this->render("confirm",array("id"=>$id));
    }
}
```

Error Coming

[image]

How to bring 39 from URL to `confirm.php` page. Please help me. Forgive me, If this is a silly question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Routing - yii-basic-app - Yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947396/url-routing-yii-basic-app-yii2)

Comment: replace  `<?echo $id;?>` to ` <?php echo $id;?>`.

Comment: No Mr @gamitg. I Did. But, still not worked. You know. You previously solved my question. This is different question. I'm not able to get 39 in my confirm.php page.

Comment: If you remove the `$id` from the `actionConfirm($id)`, is the site working then? If not, your problem is not the passing of the param, but something different.

Comment: not working after removing $id from actionConfirm, when i'm not passing any thing and no 39 in URL. confirm.php works fine Mr @Asped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that you have enabled

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in your php.ini?

also the correct short code is

You can also see this discussion:
[PHP echo vs PHP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags)

btw you don't need both if you are using a parameter in the function name here actionConfirm($id) you will have a required parameter which is filled by the parameter set by the GET params from your request URL.
Which is in your case /site/confirm/39/

So either set them in the function name

```
public function actionConfirm($id)
```

or get them manually

```
$id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
```

You don't need both.

But this isn't your problem. You still don't call the correct action in the correct controller.

Use this urlManager rules

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Those 3 which you have added are wrong remove them.

```
   '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/view',
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '/',
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '/',
```

forgot to mention that if you don't have your own rules just don't set any rules in the settings then the default rules will be used which handle most of the queries normally.

Comment: Yess. short_open_tag=on in my php.ini

Comment: if you still get the error then you have still a problem with your url routing. you should be able to render some pages. What happens when you click the about link in your menu? fix this first. then your page will render the id you have submitted.

Comment: It works fine when i click register, about etc menu Mr @Bhoft. Ok. Tell me. Is this the way which i wrote in controller to access values of URL. ??

Comment: What are the urls when you click the about link? `/site/about` ?

Comment: Mr Bhoft. 

1) http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/site/about

2) http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/site/register

3) http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/site/index

4) http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/site/contact

Comment: and if you remove the `$id` from the functions parameters than the view is correclty rendered? so only `public function actionConfirm()`

Comment: No. After removing $id from actionConfirm then also it doesn't work. But, after removing 39 from URL no parameter passing in actionConfirm(), confirm.php page comes without error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91396/discussion-between-nana-partykar-and-bhoft).